Unity 2D IK character Help(holding 2H weapons)
My IK character that have arms that follow my cursor
How can I connect arm on the right to the weapon? When I swing weapon to left, because right left arm is closer right arm cannot reach there and when I swing to right, right arm is closer so its further than weapon.
I am using an IK character and trying to do a combat system like the game “Bloody Bastards” if you know. There are effectors on the tips of lower arms and they follow IK targets and they follow my mouse position.
